# 12in rough dual flush toilet should be 10in rough

Tags: toilet

I bought a 12 in rough dual flush toilet but should have bought a 12 in rough toilet. Will I be able to keep it or will I need to switch it out? It seems to get clogged every 2-3 weeks. Is there a quick-fix solution to declog it?

Comment: if it's not lined up correctly with the closet flange that could cause blockages, and leaks.

Comment: Does it clear itself if you hold the button down and let it almost overflow? If so, I'll have to dig up my answer about lowering the chain float.

Comment: The 10" and 12" refer to the distance the drain is from the wall and has nothing to do with flushing performance.  If the toilet fit in the space, the "rough in" measurement is fine.  The only measurement relating to flush performance is gallons/liters per flush but most toilets are the same because of efficiency regulations.